# What are good resources to learn advanced SSIS?

Tags: ssis

Please recommend books/blogs to learn adavnced SSIS (2008)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Good stuff over at [SSIS Advanced Techniques](http://www.ssistalk.com/category/ssis/ssis-advanced-techniques/) and for ETL best practices in general, check out the [Kimball Group](http://www.ralphkimball.com/) (and related publications).

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend [this blog post](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/jorg_klein/archive/2010/01/04/ssis-package-design-pattern-for-loading-a-data-warehouse.aspx) which describes a SSIS package design pattern for loading a data warehouse.

It describes in detail a solution for dividing your SSIS packages into the 3 phases (Extract, Transform, Load) so that you can control and run each of them individually if necessary.

There are also many other great blogs about SSIS at http://sqlblog.com, so go there and search for SSIS.

Another advanced SSIS ressource could be the enhancement to the existing Slowly Changing Dimension Wizard in SSIS, called [SSIS Dimension Merge SCD Component](http://dimensionmergescd.codeplex.com/).